# C# Display Id of object in textfield of ComboBox and display object description in dropdown list

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to display the Id of my object in the textfield of a combobox. When I click, I want the list to display the description of the object.

This is what I get

[image: What I have]

This is what I want to see

[image: What I need]

I need to do this because I want to type the Id of the object to load the data, I don't want the user to search by description.

I tried using the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` attributes like this:

```
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

but that only displays the description in the dropdown list and returns the Id as the value, I want to display the Id in the Text attribute. I tried using the events `SelectIndexChanged`, `SelectedValueChanged`, `SelectionChangeCommitted` and changing the Text attribute to the Id but it only changes the Text to the Id and then changes it back to the Description. This is the code I tried triggering in the events:

```
ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Like I said, it changes the text to the "Id" (since the Value is the Id) but changes it back to the "Name".

Comment: Why not just add an additional field that will hold the Id? Why do you want to replace the value in the combobox?

Comment: Hey, just following up. Did my solution work for you?

Comment: @Dido the primary reason is because this is a program that is an Add-On to an already existing application which was made on PowerBuilder. What I'm trying to do is possible on PB and the main program uses it and I'm trying to keep the UI consistest, apart from that we're working on moving the platform of the main program from Powerbuilder to C#, so this would be really useful. In powerbuilder you can actually display a whole grid of data and on the Text field is show the ID of the item.

Comment: @CapnJack sorry I didn't respond, I was out of town. I'm trying to do something similar to your response right now but I'm not having much luck. I think I'll see if it's worth to make a class that extends from ComboBox or keep trying with this.

Comment: @Eriml "not having much luck", what's going wrong? Maybe I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Hey so what you're asking for isn't directly possible but here's a trick to getting it to work. First create a class like this:

public class ComboBoxItem

```
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Then, go ahead an use it like so:

```
ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
item.Text = "Item text1";
item.Value = 12;

comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

Hope that helps!